# SAS - Reducing list of unique names to a smaller list of generic names based on string similarity within the list

Tags: string, sas

I have a list of 18,000 unique entities in SAS. In most cases, individual entities refer back to a broader general entity, but differ in spelling. For example, "BANK OF MADEUPBANK" and "BK OF MADEUPBANK" would exist in the list as unique entities even though they are in fact the same entity. My goal is to group the entities that are actually the same by a generic customer name. For example, the generic name "BANK OF MADEUPBANK" would apply to "BK OF MADEUPBANK", "BANK OF MADEUP", "BK OF MAD UP", etc. This is straightforward to achieve programatically with various string searches for some common, large entities. However, there's no way to apply a string search for obscure entities that I wouldn't even know are in the list without reading through all 18,000. I'm wondering if there is a way to conduct the logical process I used on this made up bank to catch all related instances within the list of 18,000...but without knowing what the ultimate general entity is. Is there a technique that can scroll through the list of names and group them based on similarity?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a fair number of techniques, but no particularly simple one nor is there a magic bullet here.  Do some research first, and then come back with questions about specific techniques.

Comment: i would suggest using SAS Text Miner 5.1 if you have it. If you dont have it and have to solve it in a program,I builded something similar in a project some time ago by using regular expressions, but the program was large and in my specific case it only matched 80% of the names. There are also some procs like tgparse which could help... But as Joe said, the programming solutions are various and  complicated and I  think there is none with 100% chance of catching all names..